# Convert BSON to JSON to remove ObjectId

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am working with a BSON dataset with was generated from an app which was using mongodb, now I want to be able to perform some computations on it using Spark but because it has some attributes only in a BSON which is an extension of JSON and it includes some invalid expressions like ObjectId and ISODate. I want to be able to remove those e.g. from:

`"_id" : ObjectId("589895e123c572923e69f5e7"),`

to

`"_id" : "589895e123c572923e69f5e7",`.

I did something like this:

```
val rawText = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)
val rawString = rawText.take(1)(0)._2
val newText = rawString.replaceAll("""ObjectId\(([^)]+)\)""", "'$1'")
val newTextRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(newText)
newTextRDD.saveAsTextFile("newSample")
```

This works logically but the problem is that the resultant text file is saved as a single character in a single line.

`{`

`"`

`_`

`i`

`d`

`"`

`:`

`'`

`"`

`5`

`8`

`9`

`8`

`9`

`5`

`e`

`1`

`2`

`3`

`c`

`5`

`7`

`2`

`9`

`2`

`3`

`e`

`6`

`9`

`f`

`5`

`e`

`7`

`"`

`'`

`,`

How can I gracefully accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `rawText.take(1)(0)._2` and `parallelize`

Instead:

```
rawText
  .values  // Drop file name
  // Replace
  .map(_.replaceAll("""ObjectId\(([^)]+)\)""", "'$1'"))
  // Save directly without collecting
  .saveAsTextFile("newSample")
```